# Javascript integration with odoo

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-10

How to make connection of javascript with odoo?
For example: I declared a button in XML and written a function in javascript then how to call that function on XML button.

XML button declaration:

```
<footer>
    <button name="button" onclick="updatetxt(fun)" string="ok"/>
</footer>   
javascript and xml connection code:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<openerp> 
    <data> 
        <template id="assets_backend" name="Javascript_Test" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside"> 
                  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/> -->
                  <!-- <link rel="import" href="//static/src/timesheet.html"/> -->
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript_Test/static/src/js/document.js"/>
            </xpath> 
        </template> 

    </data> 
</openerp>
```

javascript code:

```
function updatetxt()
    {
        alert("hello");
    }
```

manifeast file:

```
'data': [       
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/java_script.xml',
 ],

 'js': [
 'static/src/js/document.js'
],'
```

So can I do integration with javascript on XML button?

Comment: You can start here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/web.html#odoo-javascript-module

Comment: Which version of odoo you are working on ?

Comment: I am working on odoo 10